# dein.vimでプラグイン管理、neosnippet-snippetsがインストールできない

Tags: vim

[dein] "sudo vim" is detected. This feature is disabled.
[dein] Not installed plugins: ['neosnippet-snippets']
[dein] Update started: (2017/02/08 16:57:07)
[dein] /home/〇〇〇/.cache/dein/repos/github.com/Shougo/neosnippet-snippets
[dein] Maybe wrong username or repository.
[dein] Cloning into '/home/〇〇〇/.cache/dein/repos/github.com/Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'...
[dein] Error installing plugins:
[dein]   neosnippet-snippets
[dein] Please read the error message log with the :message command.
[dein] "sudo vim" is detected. This feature is disabled.
[dein] Done: (2017/02/08 16:57:27)

以上のエラーが起こります。〇〇〇はユーザ名です。他のプラグインはインストールできました。解決方法をお願いします。

Comment: 適切な解答ありがとうございます。インストールの方はできたのですが、次のエラーメッセージがvimのインサートモードで発生しました。function neosnippet#init#_initialize[4]..<SNR>105_initialize_cache[2]..neosnippet#commands#_make_cache[22]..neosnippet#parser#_parse_snippets[19]..<SNR>111_writefile の処理中にエラーが検出されました:
行    3:
E482: ファイル /home/〇〇〇/.cache/neosnippet/=+home=+〇〇〇=+.cache=+dein=+.cache=+vimrc=+.dein=+neosnippets=+_.snip を作成できません　これは何が原因なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージにもあるように、dein.vim のインストール機能は sudo 状態では動きません。
sudo 状態で動いてしまうと、ホームディレクトリに通常ユーザーでは書き込み不可能なファイルが生成されてしまいます。